# Tomcat 9 with multiple services and separated catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, logging, configuration, multiple-instances, catalina.out

I have configured Tomcat server.xml for mutliple services (two). Both applications are developed in SpringBoot and deployed as ROOT, but on different ports.
I've configured logging.properties for logging info to separate files for both applications, but initials logs are still written to catalina.out.

Is it possible to split initial apps start logging to different catalina.out files ?

I tried to prepare logging.properties inside apps, and remove conf/logging.properties, but it seems tomcat is not using default conf/logging.properties. For double check I have tried changing catalina.out file name - no luck. Tomcat is running as systemd service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might be able to change catalina.out name in `<tomcat install dir>/conf/logging.properties`. `1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
` but it's a single file for tomcat itself. As an alternative, apps can be configured not to log to catalina.out.